# Simple Python Benchmark

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, benchmarking

The following is a quick attempt at testing some limits of my computer:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def main():
    numbers = tuple(multiprocessing.Value('Q', 0, lock=False) for _ in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count()))
    processes = tuple(multiprocessing.Process(target=count, args=(number,)) for number in numbers)
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    time.sleep(10)
    for process in processes:
        process.terminate()
    print(sum(number.value for number in numbers))


def count(number):
    while True:
        number.value += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Without changing the overall design (adding one to a variable as many times as possible within a certain time limit), is there a way to improve the performance of the code? In this case, having a higher number printed out on the same computer is better.

Comment: "attempt at testing some limits of my computer" That sounds vague, what's your actual goal? Can you describe it clearly?

Comment: @Mast The goal is to get an idea (even if it is incorrect) of how fast a central processing unit is using very little code. The program is a benchmark with simple justifications.

Comment: The algorithm seems almost random. Please expand on why this algorithm for the benchmark, as opposed to some other code.

Comment: @Donald.McLean The program has a few simple assumptions (that are not guaranteed to be correct -- and are not required to be). First, to make full use of the CPU, all cores should be exercised. Second, the amount of work accomplished can be measured within a consistent time frame. Third, add one to a variable in a tight loop can be used to get a measure of the work performed. Fourth, after the time limit has expired, the work done by each core may be totaled together. Fifth, this sum can begin to approximate the strength of the CPU. This reasoning provides a great deal of room for imprecision.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is at least one way to increase the performance of the adding loop. You should have as few bytecode instructions in that loop as possible. Right now, you are accessing the attribute of a variable. Such an operation can be eliminated by only assigning to that attribute once all of the additions have been run in the given time limit. By starting another thread waiting on a barrier, you can signal the main threading with a keyboard interrupt when the time limit has expired. When handling the exception, that is when you can assign the total number of addition operations to the number's value attribute.

```
import _thread
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time


def main():
    numbers = tuple(multiprocessing.Value('Q', 0, lock=False) for _ in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count()))
    signal = multiprocessing.Barrier(len(numbers) + 1)
    processes = tuple(multiprocessing.Process(target=count, args=(number, signal)) for number in numbers)
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    time.sleep(10)
    signal.wait()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    print(sum(number.value for number in numbers))


def count(number, signal, temp=0):
    threading.Thread(target=terminate, args=(signal,)).start()
    try:
        while True:
            temp += 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        number.value = temp


def terminate(signal):
    signal.wait()
    _thread.interrupt_main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How much better is it?

Comment: @superbrain The benchmark runs for 10 seconds. To test performance, each benchmark was run 30 times. The first test run was thrown out to allow the CPU to warm up. The original benchmark produced a mean score of 930,430,091 with a coefficient of variation equal to 1.746001%. The modified benchmark in this answer produced a mean score of 5,324,644,540 with a coefficient of variation equal to 1.595595%. While the computer itself is not any faster, the new benchmark is over 5.72 times more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer provided a great efficiency boost, but the benchmark can be simplified.

In answer to the question, the attribute access in the `count` function will slow down how many addition operations can be executed within the time limit. It would be faster to modify an argument that was provided to the function; and once the time limit has expired, then the shared variable can be updated with the results of the calculation. The `threading` module is not needed in this case; and if the individual processes are allowed to measure the time limit on their own, then there is no need for a barrier. The strategy will be to start up one process and one thread for each CPU core, use the thread to handle timing, and allow the main process threads to efficiently run the add instructions.

```
import _thread
import multiprocessing
import time


def main():
    numbers = tuple(multiprocessing.Value('Q', 0, lock=False) for _ in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count()))
    processes = tuple(multiprocessing.Process(target=count, args=(number,)) for number in numbers)
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    print(sum(number.value for number in numbers))


def count(shared, temp=0):
    _thread.start_new_thread(terminate, ())
    try:
        while True:
            temp += 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        shared.value = temp


def terminate():
    time.sleep(10)
    _thread.interrupt_main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The modified benchmark in this answer produced a mean score of 5,140,019,029 with a coefficient of variation equal to 1.414959%. While the computer itself is not any faster, the new benchmark is over 5.52 times more efficient.